# How to run DirectX code samples on Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, directx, windows-10

I'm trying to run two sample projects on Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10, both downloaded from code.msdn.

**The first** can be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-pick-and-manipulate-089639ab/view/Discussions#content).  It is a very simple sample with a rotating cube object, which was uploaded as recently as this year.  When I download the app and try to run, I get the exception pictured below: [image]

**The second** can be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b/view/Discussions#content).  When I download this app and try to run, I get the following errors:[image]

I've tinkered for a while now and I can't seem to get these to work - both recommend Visual Studio 2013, could this be the issue?  I need a simple DirectX sample running on a Universal Windows App, so if both of these are not compatible with my software, I would love any suggestions for replacements.

Comment: To answer my last question - there is a very simple DirectX sample on UWP built into Visual Studio.  Simply create a blank "DirectX 12 App (Universal Windows)" project under "Visual C++", and the default app provided will be a spinning cube with FPS values.  Would still appreciate tips on how to run the two sample apps above.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to removing creationFlags |=D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG.( In  DirectXBase::CreateDeviceResources() )

The error is because that the Direct3D Developer Runtime is OS version specific. The DirectX C++ application you have is different from your operating system’s actual DirectX 11. However the DirectX C++ application accesses only your operating system’s DirectX.

This [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) may help you, which explains the debug layer and developer runtime in detail.